# DirectXTK - The procedure entrypoint CreateFile2 could not be located in the kernel32.dll

Tags: c++, dll, windows-7, directx, kernel32

So I wanted to try using DirectXTK's spritefont class and after including all of the needed files I end up with an error poping up as the program is about to start, telling me that The procedure entrypoint CreateFile2 could not be located in the kernel32.dll. Now I have searched around for the problem and from what I can tell it seems the directxtk is trying to use windows 8 specific things (or possibly 8.1 I guess) while I am using windows 7. The general fix that people seem to suggest is to change what kind of version is used by defining

```
#define WINVER 0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x601
```

to make it use the windows 7 version. I put those defines in a header file as msdn says, but I still get the same error. If it matters I am coding it in c++ in visual studio 2013.

Comment: Did you add the defines at the very beginning of the file (before any `#include <windows.h>` like macros)?

Comment: @ChristiFati yes

#ifndef INCLUDES_H
#define INCLUDES_H

#define WINVER 0x0601
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x601

#include <windows.h>

Comment: Are you including `includes.h` in all your `.c`/`.cpp` files? Aren't there some that include standard windows headers directly? Unfortunately i can't tell you more since I don't have VS2013, in order to take a look in `FileAPI.h` to see what macros need to be defined.

Comment: @CristiFati No I don't. So should I try to put the defines in the directxtk headers? Since they are the ones messing things up.

Comment: No. This is almost as bad as placing them in VStudio's headers. What you could do is define them globally for your project. Go to _Project properties_ -> _Configuration Properties_ -> _C/C++_ -> _Preprocessor_ and in _Preprocessor definitions_ add: `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601;WINVER=0x0601;`.

Comment: @CristiFati that solved the problem! I guess it was't globally changed or something like that when I just defined it in a header. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) supports a broad array of Microsoft platforms and OS configurations, so the first step is to make sure you pick the correct VCXPROJ and/or NuGet package for your intended project and Visual C++ compiler edition.

For Windows desktop applications using VS 2013, you should use:
 `DirectXTK_Desktop_2013.vcxproj`
 -or- NuGet package [directxtk_desktop_2013](https://www.nuget.org/packages/directxtk_desktop_2013/)

The coding techniques used in the library are covered in great detail in this article [Dual-use Coding Techniques for Games](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games.aspx).

The primary control used throughout the code-base is the Windows OS target version which is set by `_WIN32_WINNT` as per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx). With the Windows 8.1 SDK (included with VS 2013) the SDK will default to using `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0603` / `_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_WINBLUE` which means to build for a Windows 8.1 or later OS. This is why the code uses `CreateFile2` which is required for the code to be usable for Windows 8.x Store, Windows phone 8.x, or Windows 10 UWP.

If, however, you use the Windows desktop projects, they build with `_WIN32_WINNT=0x0600` / `_WIN32_WINNT=_WIN32_WINNT_VISTA` and the library will make use of the APIs that work on Windows Vista SP2+KB971644 (needed for [Direct3D 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416644.aspx) and Windows 7.

In the [Direct3D Win32 Game Visual Studio template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx), I set this value in `pch.h` before including any other headers.

```
#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

The CreateFile2 reference comes from https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/LoaderHelpers.h  here:

```
    #if (_WIN32_WINNT >= _WIN32_WINNT_WIN8)
        ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(CreateFile2(fileName,
                           GENERIC_READ,
                           FILE_SHARE_READ,
                           OPEN_EXISTING,
                           nullptr)));
    #else
        ScopedHandle hFile(safe_handle(CreateFileW(fileName,
                           GENERIC_READ,
                           FILE_SHARE_READ,
                           nullptr,
                           OPEN_EXISTING,
                           FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                           nullptr)));
    #endif
```

So if the header is compiled with _WIN32_WINNT <= 0x0601, it should not use CreateFile2.  How did you try to override it?  I used the VS "Preprocessor Definitions" field and was able to force the else path.  I recommend you double check your override.

Comment: This question was asked more than 5 years ago. Now do you really expect him to reply to your comments?